# How to display all items in a list without satisfying a particular condition in C#,ASP.NET CORE?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

is it possible through FindAll()? I don't think so beacause FindAll() always need a condition right? Is there any possible way to do this?can anyone help please

This is my List

```
studentlist = new List<StudentModel>()
{
   new StudentModel{id=1,fname="john",lname="joseph",location="trivandrum",contact=786789876,email="j@gmail.com",password="a",roles="Employee" },
   new StudentModel{id=2,fname="sam",lname="joseph",location="kollam",contact=786789876,email="sam@gmail.com",password="b",roles="Admin" }
};
```

Comment: What is the condition? You need all items that doesn't satisfy this condition?

Comment: i dont need to satisy a condition .I want all the elements in the list to be displayed

Comment: If you want all, you can take the All() method from Linq. Look at my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Linq to do this. And if you want all which don't satisfying your condition, then negate it. It would something like this:

```
studentlist.Where(!yourCondition).ToList();
```

You also can use the All() method:

```
studentlist.All(condition).ToList();
```

But if you need all, simly bind(or however you want to display them) directly to your `studentlist`

Comment: its causing an error like this : ArgumentNullException
Error CS1501 No overload for method 'All' takes 0 arguments

Comment: @cyrilzyriacjoseph How do you display it? If you want all items in `studentlist`, you can simply use the variable `studentlist` without `All()` or `Where()`.

Comment: @cyrilzyriacjoseph is right. You easyli bind (or however you want to display them) to the list `studentlist`

Comment: @NimishDavidMathew i want to display it in a table format and i have that razor page.When iam simply using the variable studentlist iam  getting this error.. Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Studentdataproject.Models.StudentModel>' to 'Studentdataproject.Models.StudentModel' Studentdataproject D:\Studentdataproject\Studentdataproject\Models\StudentRep.cs 80 Active

Comment: Show us the code where you display it. The error say, that you want to convert your list to a single item of studentlist. So you have a problem with your casting.

Comment: }
@{Studentdataproject.Models.StudentModel obj1 = ViewBag.StudentModel;
}

tr>
            <td>@obj1.id</td>
            <td>@obj1.fname</td>
            <td>@obj1.lname</td>
            <td>@obj1.location</td>
            <td>@obj1.contact</td>
            <td>@obj1.email</td>
            <td>@obj1.password</td>
            <td>@obj1.roles</td>
        </tr> //i have omitted some unnecessary code

Comment: You have to define your model as IEnumerable. Here are some good examples: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/f82e9a/data-displaying-in-table-format-in-diffrent-ways-in-mvc/